# Flutter REST api call with Basic auth returns 401, despite correct credentials

Tags: flutter, rest, basic-authentication

I'm trying to call an api from flutter but i keep getting 401 Unauthorized. According to the api documentation it uses basic authentiocation and is UTF-8 encoded. The username and password is provided by the docs and if try the api in a web browser and enter those credentials it goes through and i recieve the data. This is the code i'm using in flutter:

```
  Future<void> requestData() async {
    String username = 'abc';
    String password = '123';
    String basicAuth = 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));
    Response r = await get(
        Uri.parse('http://api.example.com'),
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: basicAuth,
        });
    print(r.body);
    print(r.statusCode);
  }
```

I've also tried this variation which gave the same result:

```
headers: <String, String>{
  'authorization': basicAuth
}
```

Seeing as the username and password are correct there must be something wrong with how i make the call, but i've tried to do it a bunch of different ways and nothing works. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just to be clear, you have to pass login details as a header in a get request?

Comment: Is there a way to compare the encoded un and pw of the web browser to what is produced in Flutter?

Comment: @Denzel Yes, you need to authenticate the request with a username and password (which are freely availible). How to do it is what i'm struggling with.

Comment: Have you tested this API on postman to see how it behaves?

Comment: @Denzel I just tried that with Basic Auth, it gave the same result (401). It's weird because when i use the credentials in a browser it works. I'm not very experienced with api authorization but the documentation clearly states that it uses "Basic Auth".

Comment: Is the api something you can share?

Comment: @eimmer That solved the problem! Turns out the documentation was wrong and the api used something called "Digest authentication". I looked into how to implement that and it worked, thanks!

Comment: @Denzel It's http://tagtider.net/api/. But i solved the problem, the documentation seems to be outdated and it uses "Digest authentication".

Comment: Okay sounds good

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, there is no need of token or basic auth while doing login. And login is post method not get.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I'm trying to make a get-request which is protected by basic-auth. I need to, somehow, use credentials when making the request or it returns 401.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the documentation i read was outdated/incorrect. The api uses "Digest authentication" which i looked up and was able to implement. This is the code if anyone is interested:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:http_auth/http_auth.dart';

...

Response res = await DigestAuthClient("USERNAME", "PASSWORD")
      .get(Uri.parse("API_URL")).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 20));
```